# running projects downloaded from github

Tags: asp.net-mvc, github

I have downloaded a project from github. When I am trying to run the project, I am getting errors as

```
The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) strakcinema 
The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  strakcinema
```

getting same errors for `WebPages, Mvc, Optimization`

I checked the references dll files, **Copy Local is set to True**.

Web config code block::

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1" newVersion="4.0.2.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

What is the issue, how to solve this issue?

Comment: In which page you are getting this error.

Comment: Project Url:: `https://github.com/rishi-karki/StarkCinema`. getting error in `Signin.cshtml`

Comment: I successfully build this solution, I hope you are starting project from .sln file.

Comment: Getting the error `Your project file uses a newer version of the TypeScript compiler and tools than supported by this version of Visual Studio.  Your project may be using TypeScript language features that will result in errors when compiling with this version of the TypeScript tools.  To remove this warning, remove the <TypeScriptToolsVersion> element from your project file.`

Comment: On which page you are getting this error.

Comment: Install 'Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild' package from Nuget., then warning will gone, But warning is nothing do with the the project.